# How to determine subject, object and other words in a Context

Tags: c#, nlp

Im trying to implement NLP in my project,
I need to Tag the words as Person,Location ,Organix=sation etc..If any body knows the logic please let me know..
Regards,
Stack

Comment: Are you looking for link to a library of NLP implementations?  Or do you want to write your own from scratch?

Comment: im looking for a link to nlp library implementation,parsing ,chunking,tokenising all these functionalities i achived, now i need to tag them...

Comment: You probably also want to note the language(s) and genre(s) you're interested in. Your implementation choices may depend to some degree on the availability of models matched to your target domains, and the ease of training or adapting models from your own domain-specific training corpora.

Answer (score 2):

The task you want to perform is known as [Named Entity Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity_recognition) (NER).

The majority of software for doing NER is in Java. For example, the [Stanford NER](http://nlp.stanford.edu/ner/index.shtml) system and the [OpenNLP NER](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/) system. There are far fewer similar libraries written in C#, however I found [SharpNLP](http://www.codeplex.com/sharpnlp) through a Google search. I have not used it personally so I have no idea how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice web-service by Reuters: http://www.opencalais.com/.
You can access it via an API.

I thought that the demo was impressive http://viewer.opencalais.com/.

I did not pursue it further, as I want to create a German application. Calais is only supporting English.